# Get update from external json value without full page refresh

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a **"status.json"** file that is updated regularly ... my goal is to read this value and display a React App updating only the text ... I'm having problems because whenever the file is updated the page entire update causing an infinite load loop

**status.json**

```
{
  "data": { "value": 15 } 
}
```

**React App**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function myData() {
  const[json, setJson] = useState(require('./status.json'));

  useEffect(() => {
    setJson(require('./status.json')); 

},[]);

  return (
    <div class="container">
      {json.data.value}
    </div>
  );

}

export default myData
```

Refresh Loop:

[refresh loop gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk1sJ.gif)

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function myData() {
  const[json, setJson] = useState(require('./status.json'));
  /*
  useEffect(() => {
    setJson(require('./status.json')); 

  },[json]);  // it causes infinite loop
 */
  //ComponentDidMount
  useEffect(()=>{
    setJson(require('./status.json'));
  },[]);

  return (
    <div class="container">
      {json.data.value}
    </div>
  );

}

export default myData
```

Comment: thanks for the note, but the page keeps updating very quickly, causing the "loop", I want to update only the text and not the entire page. [link](https://i.imgur.com/3Vezo4L.gif)